# powershell java invalid thread stack size error

Tags: java, powershell, stack

I'm tasked with converting some Windows scripts to PowerShell versions. The conversion is going good except for some minor issues. Top issue involves a Java call that we use to query a database and generate XML or HTML files. When I run this from a Windows script no problem:

java  **-Xss1m** -cp ../lib/;../lib/jtds-1.3.1.jar;../lib/ojdbc6.jar DBDownloader TMPDBNAME ../sql/MTD_MTTR_Detail_v7.sql ../out/drilldown/%fileName1%  >> ..\logs\mtd.log 2>&1

But when I run this from a PowerShell script I get this error:

*LASTEXITCODE:1 Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
**Invalid thread stack size: -Xss1m -cp***

The call is made using the & call operator. I wrote a library function for all the script to use and it make a call similar to the following:

*$output = [string] (& $jvApp $jvArg1 $jvArg2 $jvArg3 $dbArg $sqlArg $lastArg *>> $logArg 2>&1)*

The args for this call are the following:

sqlName: MTD_MTTR_Detail_v7

jvArg1:  -Xss1m -cp

jvArg2:  ../lib/;../lib/jtds-1.3.1.jar;../lib/ojdbc6.jar

jvArg3:  DBDownloader

dbArg:   TMPDBNAME

sqlArg:  ..\sql\MTD_MTTR_Detail_v7.sql

lastArg: ..\out\drilldown\MTD_MTTR_Detail.xml

logArg:  ..\logs\mtd.log

I also set these environment variables:

env:Path:      C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin;...

env:JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\;

env:CLASSPATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib;

What is weird is that the call will work and produce the XML or HTML file if I take out the stack size argument. I've also tried several smaller stack size settings down to 128k with no luck.

While the call works now without the setting, I'm concerned it may fail in the future. I believe they put this due the complex SQL statement used the large amounts of data they were querying and processing.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like the `&` call operator is taking `$jvArg1` as a single argument, and it contains `-Xss1m -cp`, and this is confusing the java runtime.  Try breaking `$jvArg1` into `$jvArg1a` which is `-Xss1m` and `$jvArg1b` which is `-cp`.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:  When I split up the two args in jvArg1 into two different variables the Java call worked with no stack size error.  I guess Java was reading the first arg as one big string and the space in between didn't matter. It must have thought the -cp was part of the stack size argument.